# Row selecting in MVC doesn't work

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, razor

**I could make the row getting selected through this coding but it seems to allow me selecting multiple rows.**

```
1:   $('#LineTables tbody').on('click', 'tr', function () {
2:          console.log("Row Clicked");
3:          if ($(this).hasClass('selected')) {
4:              $(this).removeClass('selected');
5:              console.log("Removed Selected Class");
6:          }
7:          else {
8:              $(this).addClass('selected');
9:              console.log("Added Selected Class");
10:         }
11:     });
```

**I want to allow only a single row selection. The source code from Datatables.net is this code below. I always get an Error in the console that tells me TypeError: $(...).DataTable is not a function. I put all the js and css files that were given on the website in my project correctly. Why am I still getting this Error message from the console.
Datatables.net also confirms the code**

> Initialising DataTables
>
> That's almost it! We've got the HTML table we want to enhance, and we've got all the >software and styles we need. All that is now required is to to tell DataTables to >actually work its magic on the table. This is done with a few lines of Javascript:

```
   $(document).ready( function () {
       $('#table_id').DataTable();
   } )}
```

source code from Datatables.net

```
1:   $(document).ready(function() {
2:   var table = $('#example').DataTable();
3: 
4:   $('#example tbody').on( 'click', 'tr', function () {
5:       if ( $(this).hasClass('selected') ) {
6:           $(this).removeClass('selected');
7:       }
8:       else {
9:           table.$('tr.selected').removeClass('selected');
10:          $(this).addClass('selected');
11:       }
12:      });
13:    });
```

Comment: can you provide rendered html?

Comment: First of all you should be using @Url.Content for your scripts if this is mvc.

Comment: Is there any error in console when you click the row?

Comment: @MikeCheel What's the Matter with @ Url.Content and @ Html.Content. Doesn't answers my needs right now.

Comment: @MaulikAnand Where do i provide the rendered html? No thing happens when clicking the row. No error even.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$('#LineTables tbody').on('click', 'tr', function () {
    console.log("Row Clicked");

    if ($(this).hasClass('selected')) {
        $(this).removeClass('selected');
        console.log("Removed Selected Class");

    }
    else {
        table.$('tr.selected').removeClass('selected');
        $(this).addClass('selected');
        console.log("Added Selected Class");

    }
});
```

Try this and confirm that this events are showing in console.

Comment: Console ErrorThe connection to ws://localhost:6497.... was interrupted while the page was loading. browserLink:62
no element found abort:1
TypeError: $(...).dataTable is not a function 1:63
Use of getPreventDefault() is deprecated.  Use defaultPrevented instead.

Comment: so the data table is not working, double check the dataTable js file reference, and check in the console/resources  , that the data table is correctly loaded, or try to get the new file of dataTable, in case there is any problem with current file

Comment: I was able to select. I updated my post. But the next problem I still can't find the function Datatables. I re-inserted every script but it doesn't seem to help.

Comment: @user3758689  try `$('#LineTables').dataTable();` , i mean the letter `d` is in lower case as shown on dataTable Documentation **[HERE](http://www.datatables.net/examples/basic_init/zero_configuration.html)**